# Оптимизация кода в python: извлечение строк из запроса к БД

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, оптимизация, psycopg2

Здравствуйте.
Используя библиотеку psycopg2 из БД (postgresql) я извлёк несколько строк с данными.

```
cur.execute(querry)
```

К примеру, содержимое строк следующее:

```
>>for row in cur:
    row[0]+" "+row[1]
Иванов Москва
Петров Пенза
Сидоров Волгоград
Кузнецов Смоленск
```

Теперь вопрос: как мне не прогоняя весь цикл, сразу из курсора можно извлечь 3 строку "Сидоров Волгоград", не прибегая к повторному запросу к БД для извлечения именно нужной записи?

Comment: Без цикла и без повторного запроса? Противоречащие друг другу условия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, в psycopg2 (так же как и во многих других библиотеках для подключения к БД) у объекта курсора есть метод fetchall(), которым вы можете выгрузить его содержимое в список и дальше уже к нему обращаться по индексу.

При этом помните, что если вы хотите читать из результатов запроса строки по номеру, то в запросе нужно явно указывать сортировку через ORDER BY - иначе стандарт sql не гарантирует, что строки результата будут в каком-то ожидаемом вами порядке.

Comment: Хз-хз, внутри fetchall скорее всего найдётся какой-нибудь цикл, аналогичный циклу из вопроса, а в условии сказано «не прогоняя весь цикл»)

Answer (score 2):

**Никак, как мне кажется.** Судя по всему, `cur.execute` отдает генератор, а если номер нужного элемента неизвестен, то без цикла из итератора значение *не извлечь*.